# ReactJS Component not updating on parent state change

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I have a blog section in my ReactJS that pulls posts from a headless CMS, page uses pagination and all works perfectly fine, however, within each post item, i call a component to input the authors name > so basically i pull an ID from the headless api, the i pass that through to the component and return the name of the author.

This works fine the first time round, but whenever i use the pages pagination, it doesn't bring back anything else from the component regardless of the information being passed by the prop. Here's my code;

Blog page;

```
getPosts(){
        if(this.state.posts.length){
            return this.state.posts.map((content,index) => {
                var url = content.Title.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
                url = url.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
                    return(
                        <Col md={4} className="mb-4" key={index}>
                            
                            {({isVisible}) => 
                            <Card>
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <Link to={{ pathname: `/posts/${url}` }}>
                                        <Card.Title>{this.truncateOnWord(content.Title,50)}</Card.Title>
                                    </Link>
                                    <Card.Text>{this.truncateOnWord(content.SEOMetaDescription,150)}</Card.Text>
                                </Card.Body>
                                <Card.Footer>
                                    <PortraitTest displayFromAPIID={content.Author._id}></PortraitTest>
                                </Card.Footer>
                            </Card>
                            } 
                        </Col>
                    );
            })
        }
    }

handlePageClick = data => {
        var myElement = document.getElementById('articles');
        var topPos = myElement.offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo({top: topPos, behavior: 'smooth'});

        var selected = data.selected + 1;
        var offset = ((selected * this.state.perPage) - this.state.perPage);
        var limit = (this.state.perPage * selected);
    
        this.setState({ offset: offset, limit: limit }, () => {
          this.loadAPI();
        });
    };

render() {
        return (
            <div>
                        <CardDeck>
                            {this.getPosts()}
                        </CardDeck>

                        <ReactPaginate
                        previousLabel='&laquo;'
                        previousClassName={ 'previousBtn'}
                        nextLabel='&raquo;'
                        nextClassName={'nextBtn'}
                        breakLabel={'...'}
                        breakClassName={'break-me'}
                        activeClassName={'active'}
                        pageClassName={'page-item'}
                        pageLinkClassName={'page-link'}
                        containerClassName={'pagination'}
                        subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
                        pageCount={this.state.pageCount}
                        marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                        pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                        onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
                    />
           </div>
        );
}
```

Author Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class PortraitTest extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            displayFromAPIID: this.props.displayFromAPIID,
            name: null,
            apiID: null,
        }
        this.portraits = [
            { 
                'name': 'Name 1',
                'apiID': '5d84ba9c0a011064444a243e',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 2',
                'apiID': '5d84bad40a011064444a2441',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 3',
                'apiID': '5d84d4d00a011064444a244d',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 4',
                'apiID': '5d84ba480a011064444a243a',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 5',
                'apiID': '5d84d4900a011064444a244c',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 6',
                'apiID': '5d84baeb0a011064444a2442',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 7',
                'apiID': '5d84baaf0a011064444a243f',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 8',
                'apiID': '5d84ba720a011064444a243c',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 9',
                'apiID': '5d84d4120a011064444a244a',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 10',
                'apiID': '5d84d4640a011064444a244b',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 11',
                'apiID': '5d84b93a0a011064444a2439',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 12',
                'apiID': '5d84d3b60a011064444a2449',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 13',
                'apiID': '5d84bac00a011064444a2440',
            },
            { 
                'name': 'Name 14',
                'apiID': '5d84ba870a011064444a243d',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Name 15',
                'apiID': '5d84ba5e0a011064444a243b',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Name 16',
                'apiID': '5dd7cbf984b07d000dc63b2e',
            }
            ]
        
    }

    returnObj(){
        for (var i = 0; i < this.portraits.length; i++) {
            if(this.state.displayFromAPIID === Object.values(this.portraits[i])[1]){
                return(
                    <div>
                        <p><b>{Object.values(this.portraits[i])[0]}<br/>{Object.values(this.portraits[i])[1]}<br/>{this.props.displayFromAPIID}</b></p>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.returnObj()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PortraitTest;
```

Below is a screenshot of the component outputting to the blog page.

[image: screenshot of issue]

Anyone have any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Please note that actually the page the blog articles are on is perfectly fine and working as expected, pulling correct data from API and pagination works perfectly, it's the component I'm requesting information from that doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Hi do the calls actually happen when you click on your pagination? Have you checked the `Network>XHR` section of the devTool?

Comment: Everytime the pagination is clicked it loads the next 9 blog items. This pulls the correct data from our api. You can see from the screenshot the data being sent through to the component changes (2nd ID string on 2nd section), but the company doesn’t provide anything new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the constructor is not called on subsequent renders, it is only called once to initialise the component. To update your state when the properties change, you must implement componentDidUpdate.

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.displayFromAPIID !== prevProps.displayFromAPIID) {
    this.setState({displayFromAPIID: this.props.displayFromAPIID});
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah mate, that’s it!!! I knew it had something to do with the component updating but I couldn’t join the dots! Thank you!!!